# Need to store high precision decimal values in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, decimal

I have little experience with MongoDB. I am usual working on large scale SQL server DBs.

MongoDB only supports double and **there is no decimal**. The C# driver serializes decimals as strings.

- What functionality do I miss if I store decimals as strings in
  MongoDB?
- Is there a way to set a default serialization of decimals as double
  (AllowTruncation) without having to put an Attribute on each
  property?
- What do I lose in precision if I used Bson double?

Thanks for your help!

### **UPDATE**

I have an existing application model that uses decimals in C#. I want to use MongoDB as a new DB layer and change as little in the existing app as possible. Thats why I am looking for a way to map *decimals* in C# to *double* in MongoDB.
I understand that I loose precision and would have to analyze the side effects of it. My only remaining question is to know if there is a way to set a default serialization of decimals as double.
Thanks again. Great answers and comments so far.

Comment: If you need decimal precision, do not use doubles. You risk changing the data by doing so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - What about Decimal type of value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value)

Comment: .... and the still open issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1393

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Great info.I still need to know how to set a default serialoization of decimals to double in C#.
the question referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value is not the same

Comment: Why not just use doubles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will answer your question partially (because I do not know much about C#).

**So what will you lose if you will store decimals as strings.**

- your numbers on average would weight more (each double number [cost 8 bytes to store](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) which means that every string that has more then 8 chars will weight more). Because of these your indexes (if they will be built on this field would grow)
- you will not be able to use operators which takes numbers as arguments [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc), [$bit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit), [$mod](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/mod/#op._S_mod), [$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/min/#up._S_min), [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max) and in 2.6 version [$mul](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/mul/#up._S_mul). (May be I forgot something)
- you will not be able to compare numbers (may be '1.65' and '1.23' is comparable as a string, but definitely not numbers with e and minuses somewhere in between). Because of this operations which build on top of comparison like [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/), and all these [$gte, $gt, $lte, $lt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) will not work correctly.

**What will you lose in precision if you store decimal as double**:

- based on [this, Decimal in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) has 28-29 significant digits, whereas looking at my first link and checking the [spec for double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary64) you see that it has 15-17 significant digits. This is basically what you will lose
- another really important thing which people sometimes forget when dealing with double floats is illustrated below:

.

```
db.c.insert({_id : 1, b : 3.44}) 
db.c.update({_id : 1},{$inc : {b : 1}})
db.c.find({b: 4.44})  // WTf, where is my document? There is nothing there
```

**Regarding the 2-nd subquestion:**

> Is there a way to set a default serialization of decimals as double
>   (AllowTruncation) without having to put an Attribute on each property?

I do not really understood it, so I hope someone would be able to answer it.

Answer (score 8):

As of Mongodb 3.4 and the 2.4 Mongodb C# driver, decimal types are supported.

The properties of your document must have the `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]` attribute found in the `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes` namespace.

this will map to `"YourDecimalValue" : NumberDecimal("100.0000")` in MongodDB. Robomongo supports the new decimal type from version 1.1 Beta.

Comment: Many thanks for answering an almost 4 year old question!