# Linq order by decimal field sorts like a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm totally baffled and cannot find anything on the internet about this, so I must be doing something wrong?

```
 _positionsRepo.GetAllTrades().OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPLPercent).ToList();
```

TotalPLPercent is a decimal field.  the result order sorts like this:

```
96.76
95.54
8.54
75.55
231.22
13
```

Obviously, this is wrong. I tested the sort against another field that was a double, and it worked as expected. What am I missing here about decimals in C#?

I am using the Mongo DB C# driver.

Comment: Try putting a `.ToList().` in between `GetAllTrades()` and `OrderByDescending()`. That way, the list will be sorted in memory, rather than in the database (which I suspect is something to do with it).

Comment: Make sure TotalPLPercent is not string.

Comment: it's absolutely not a string...  but sorts like one, hence the confusion.

Comment: OK, looks like MongoDB does not have a native decimal type. Are you *sure* it's not a string? It might serialize to a C# decimal, but in the database, it may be a string.

Comment: hey blorgbeard got the answer.  i had a suspicion of trying this, but didn't think this could be causing it!  works fine now.  but now i don't get the performance benefit of the deferred execution because the ToList gets the ENTIRE collection from the DB, THEN sorts.  sounds like a bug in he monggoDB C# driver.

Comment: yes blorgbeard, that sounds right.  i bet it's a string in the database.  seems like a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The C# Mongo DB driver serializes `decimal` as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036529/need-to-store-high-precision-decimal-values-in-mongodb) (The [driver source-code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/060c21807c7bb921bf36e08801554aaaa44abfd6/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/DecimalSerializer.cs) corroborates this).

It does this because there is no BSON type for decimal - double does not have the same precision. Unfortunately it means you can't compare "decimal" values as numbers.

You could sort the data in memory, like this:

```
_positionsRepo.GetAllTrades()
   .ToList()
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPLPercent)
   .ToList();
```

Another option would be to store the number of cents (or hundredths of cents) as a long integer. Then you can sort them normally, and you just have to divide by 100 (or 10,000) to get your real value.

Comment: thanks.  works.  but seems like not ideal for performance now.

Comment: Well, you are retrieving all rows anyway, I don't think it will make *too* much difference, unless your data-set is really large.

Comment: you have to make it vice versa , if you need order descending make it ascending \

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is the problem with `MongoDB Driver for C#`. Check this open issue here -

[the 'System.Decimal' type save as 'String'](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-196?jql=text%20~%20%22decimal%22)

As you can see since `Decimal` is saved as `String`, it surely will sort like a string. I think you should try `double` instead of `decimal` until they fix this issue.

Comment: It's dangerous to use `double` for currency values - you get floating point rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the type of x is Decimal? It looks like it's doing a string ordering. (I'd put a breakpoint on "x.TotalPLPercent" and then evaluate x's type to double verify it's what I thought it was.)

Comment: yeah it's most definitely a decimal.  i think it's a bug in the mongodb C# driver with decimals.  since maybe mongo looks at it as a string.  check the comments on my question, the solution is there.  not ideal, but it works.