# OrderBy and OrderByDescending query on a decimal stored as a string

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query

I'm trying to performing `OrderBy` decimal property on Mongo DB collection using C# mongo driver. Since the decimal is storing has string, I am not able to achieve this. How can I perform the OrderBy on decimal property?

//In the model

```
public decimal PayAmount { get; set; }
```

//While creating a query

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Documents.Job>();
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Status == jobStatus);
var jobdata = context.Jobs.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
var query = from a in jobdata  select new { //selects Field here  };
query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.PayAmount); // this does not sort and PayAmount is decimal type
var jobs = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: can you update with complete query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
query.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.PayAmount));
```

But really I found you need to write a custom serializer for decimal there are some examples around if you search for serializing decimal in mongo.

This is not tested and you might need to write a custom serializer for decimal as mentioned.

Comment: query = query.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.PayAmount)); Throws exception error as "Only fields are allowed in a $sort." from "MongoDB.Driver"

Comment: Out of interest why are you storing it as string?

Comment: In refference to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772173/linq-order-by-decimal-field-sorts-like-a-string I undersatnd that decimal values are stored as string in mongo db.

Comment: Are you using POCO to store your object.  I would have the property set as decimal I used it a while back and the drive did take care of the conversion. As the link you refer to is very outdated and new features have been added to the driver.

Comment: No i am not using POCO..I am able to achieve the order by on making the changes to my model and DB as this
   
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]                                           
 public decimal PayAmount { get; set; }.     But the problem with this is on QA or Production, we are using Azure cosmos DB ... after the above model change, i am getting error on query as "Command aggregate failed: 'Decimal128' is not supported." .... Since using C# Mongo db driver over Cosmos Db. Any help on the same.

Comment: I see I have not had much experience with Cosmos so maybe someone can advise.