# Sortable decimal value (no double/float). Which way to choose?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, decimal, bigdecimal

I was looking how to save decimals using MongoDB and stumbled across a few ideas.

1. Save it as String (as I'm using Java Spring Framework, this is the default implementation)

   `value: "3.44"`
2. Save it the ebay way using a nested document with the unscaled value + scale: http://www.technology-ebay.de/the-teams/mobile-de/blog/mapping-bigdecimals-with-morphia-for-mongodb.html

   `value: { unscaled: NumberLong(344) , scale: 2 }`
3. Save the digits before and behind the decimal point separately

   `value: { major: 3 , minor: 44 }`

Basically I'd say:

1. Is useless, because I can't sort it as numbers (i.e. `"9" > "12"`)
2. If ebay uses this, it can't be that bad. But I can't figure out how to sort those values?!
3. Sort is pretty easy: `db.collection.find().sort({"value.major":1, "value.minor":1})`

### Questions:

How do you implement it?

How does sorting work using approach `2.`?

Thank you!

### Workarounds:

1. Store `major` as integer and `minor` as string:

   `value: { major: 3 , minor: "44" }`
2. Define the max. precision of your decimal and then you can fill the minor value with zeros. For example with precision = 10:

   `value: { major: 3 , minor: 4400000000 }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - What about Decimal type of value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value)

Comment: In your referenced question the the answer is to use an int, which has a fixed number of digits behind the decimal point. But `this` question is about **sorting** *and* **variable number of digits behind the decimal point**.

Comment: Your 3rd option doesn't work. Imagine if it were `3.5` being stored. Unless you store the `"minor"` as a string value, `44` is greater than `5`. `"44"` however is less than `"5"`.

Comment: The second one isn't sortable in a meaningful way on the database server. It's only useful as a data value.

Comment: Dammit, you are right. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: As I mentioned, you could do #3 if the `minor` value was stored as a string. Or, wait a few more years for MongoDB to implement the data type properly. :)  (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1393)

Comment: Hm, I think I can only wait a few more days, not years. But you're right, when using a String as minor the sorting would work. That's really a badass hacky solution, but it seems to be the only working solution...

Comment: An alternative of course would be, to say: My Decimal has a precision of 12, and then fill the `minor` value with `000000` until it's 12 digits long. I.e. `12.44` becomes `major: 12` and `minor: 440000000000`.