# Float number overflows when export MongDB collection to JSON via mongoexport

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. I've inserted a float number into a collection. However, when I export that collection via mongoexport, the float number changes.

This is what in the database:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56653e23a6b56616ba417bcd"), "id" : "601318", "name" : "中国平安", "buy" : [ { "time" : ISODate("2015-06-15T01:30:00Z"), "price" : 86.9, "quantity" : 1000, "value" : 87074.4 } ], "sell" : [ { "time" : ISODate("2015-07-07T01:30:00Z"), "price" : 80.88, "quantity" : 1000, "value" : 80636.76 } ] }

This is when it's exported to json:

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "56653e23a6b56616ba417bcd" }, "id" : "601318", "name" : "中国平安", "buy" : [ { "time" : { "$date" : "2015-06-15T09:30:00.000+0800" }, "price" : 86.90000000000001, "quantity" : 1000, "value" : 87074.39999999999 } ], "sell" : [ { "time" : { "$date" : "2015-07-07T09:30:00.000+0800" }, "price" : 80.88, "quantity" : 1000, "value" : 80636.75999999999 } ] }

How to avoid this overflow?

Comment: How did you store these values in mongodb ? using ruby calculations?

Comment: Via Node.js. Using db.collection('Opers2015').insertOne({....})

Answer (score 0):

Store the value as an integer: 8063676 (cents or whatever).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value).