# Spring Data MongoDB BigDecimal support

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

guys I have a doubt related to BigDecimal value support by Spring Data MongoDB, could someone help me with some news about it, if there will be support for this type, or if anyone knows a workaround to supply my needs. That's the deal: I'm working on a project where we use MongoDB as a DB and Spring as framework, we would like to save the fields where we are supposed to get money values in the database as BigDecimal, I've read that mongo only accepts double as a float number, but I don't think this type is going to be useful. Could you guys give me some light about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - What about Decimal type of value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Spring Data MongoDB converts `BigDecimal` values to `String` on write and back to when reading. Please have a look at the [data mapping and type conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-conversion) section of the reference manual.

The default conversion can be modified via `@Field(targetType=...)` as shown below.

```java
@Field(targetType = DECIMAL128)
private BigDecimal value;
```

Answer (score 19):

You can change the converter of `BigDecimal` do `Decimal128` which is the java representation of [`NumberDecimal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#numeric-decimal) since mongo 3.4:

```
@Bean
public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
    return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(

        new Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128>() {

            @Override
            public Decimal128 convert(@NonNull BigDecimal source) {
                return new Decimal128(source);
            }
        },

        new Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal>() {

            @Override
            public BigDecimal convert(@NonNull Decimal128 source) {
                return source.bigDecimalValue();
            }

        }


    ));

}
```

---

Actually since Spring Data 2.0.7.RELEASE the above changes to following:

```
@Bean
public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
    return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
        new BigDecimalDecimal128Converter(),
        new Decimal128BigDecimalConverter()
    ));

}

@WritingConverter
private static class BigDecimalDecimal128Converter implements Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128> {

    @Override
    public Decimal128 convert(@NonNull BigDecimal source) {
        return new Decimal128(source);
    }
}

@ReadingConverter
private static class Decimal128BigDecimalConverter implements Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convert(@NonNull Decimal128 source) {
        return source.bigDecimalValue();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

As is documented at the Spring Data MongoDB - Reference Documentation [18.6. Custom Conversions - Overriding Default Mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters):

The most trivial way of influencing the mapping result is by specifying the desired native MongoDB target type via the `@Field` annotation. This allows to work with non MongoDB types like `BigDecimal` in the domain model while persisting values in native `org.bson.types.Decimal128` format.

```java
public class Payment {

  @Field(targetType = FieldType.DECIMAL128) 
  BigDecimal value;

}
```

The desired target type is explicitly defined as `Decimal128` which translates to `NumberDecimal`. Otherwise the `BigDecimal` value would have been turned into a `String`:

```json
{
  "value" : NumberDecimal(2.099)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a corner case where I had a lot of decimals and Decimal128`s constructor raised the following exception:

```
Failed to convert from type [java.math.BigDecimal] to type [org.bson.types.Decimal128] for value '21.6000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: Conversion to Decimal128 would require inexact rounding of 21.6000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250
```

The Solution to this was to round down the input:

```
new Decimal128(source.round(MathContext.DECIMAL128))
```

Comment: This is actually very good point - BigDecimal has basically unlimited number of decimal places (limited by memory), NumberDecimal supports 34 decimal places. So if you want to use this conversion you need to round it which might not be an option for some people