# Criteria query for big decimal in mongotemplate

Tags: mongodb, criteria, mongotemplate

I have an entity class where I have a value as the salary.
Datatype of salary is bigdecimal.
Now I want to perform one query on this entity where I have 2 values, fromSalary and toSalary.
I want all the employees with salary > fromSalary and salary < toSalary.
I am using mongodb as datastore and using mongotemplate criteria query for this operation.

Salary is in Bigdeciaml,
fromSalary and toSalary are in Double.

I tried 2 ways.

Criteria.where(Salary).gte(new BigDecimal(fromSalary)).lte(new BigDecimal(toSalary))) ;
Criteria.where(Salary).gte(fromSalary).lte(toSalary)) ;

When I perform these operation, I get empty response in both the cases even though I have data in this range in my database.

How to perform range operation on bigdecimal?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is [Spring Data MongoDB converts `BigDecimal` values to `String` by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-conversion), so your **salary** field is actually being stored as `String` in MongoDB.

You can modify the default conversion with `@Field` annotation like this:

```
@Field(targetType = FieldType.DECIMAL128)
private BigDecimal salary;
```

This way the salary field's value will be stored as MongoDB's native `Decimal128` type, and the queries in your question will work as you expect.

You can check the relevant answer from Christoph Strobl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37959612/2560718).