# BigDecimal is stored in string in spring data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Document(collection = "loanDetails")
class LoanDetails {
    @Transient
    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "loanDetails
    @Id
    String id

    String loanId
    String loanUUID
    String loanStatus
    Date loanDateCreated
    Date loanLastUpdated
    BigDecimal loanAmount //Stores in String
}
```

I declared a class LoanDetails and a field with BigDecimal type loanAmount in it
Whenever i saved some data in this collection

1. It get stores as a string in mongo db database
2. while getting the records from database i am getting the error of
   **Failed to decode 'LoandDetails'. Decoding 'loanAmount' errored with:
   readDecimal can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DECIMAL128,
   not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.**

I tried to add annotation over loanAmount field

```
@Field(targetType = Decimal128) // This also throws error does not contain targetType attribute attached screenshot for the same
BigDecimal loanAmount
```

[image]

Comment: Add a [java] tag to the question for proper syntax highlighting.

Comment: i am using groovy as a language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data MongoDB BigDecimal support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950296/spring-data-mongodb-bigdecimal-support)

Comment: No @Valijon 
I tried @Field(targetType = Decimal128) but it did not worked

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you need to drop / migrate your already created `loanDetails`, since the `loanAmount` field is persisted as `String`.

By adding `@Field(targetType = FieldType.DECIMAL128)` to your `loanAmount` field it should work.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.FieldType;
...

@Field(targetType = FieldType.DECIMAL128)
BigDecimal loanAmount;
...

public LoanDetails() {
    loanAmount = new BigDecimal(21.905334472656250);
}
...
 
template.save(loan);

template.find(new Query(), org.bson.Document.class, "loanDetails").forEach(l -> {
    System.out.println(l.get("loanAmount").getClass().getName() + " " + l.get("loanAmount"));   
});
//org.bson.types.Decimal128 21.90533447265625
    
template.findAll(LoanDetails.class).forEach(l -> {
    System.out.println(l.loanAmount.getClass().getName() + " " + l.loanAmount); 
});
//java.math.BigDecimal 21.90533447265625
```

If you get `Conversion to Decimal128 would require inexact rounding of XXX`

> Note: The `Decimal128` type only supports up to 34 digits of precision.  (Generally, "precision" = total # of digits, while "scale" = # of decimal digits).   Whereas a Java BigDecimal can go higher.  So, before saving to the DB, you need to round the BigDecimal value (e.g. use `BigDecimal.setScale()`) method.

[BigDecimalConverter issue](https://groups.google.com/g/morphia/c/aUu1Z6RnYA8) | [Decimal128](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/Decimal128.java#L244)

Comment: i mentioned in my question that i tried this @Field(targetType = FieldType.DECIMAL128) but this not work the error is "does not contain targetType attribute"

Comment: @chaitanyagupta read carefully my answer, you need to drop your already persisted data in order to make it work.

Comment: yes i understand but it is that error i restricting my code to compile as 
Intellij IDE

Comment: @chaitanyagupta Update your question with screenshot please, with the error. The solution works perfectly in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Question is Updated.

Comment: @chaitanyagupta Seems wrong import https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/FieldType.html#DECIMAL128

Comment: import is correct import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field

Comment: import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field
 does not contain FieldType

Answer (score -1):

You can register a custom converted in mongo config

```
@Configuration        
public class MongoConfig
{

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions()
    {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
                new BigDecimalToDocumentWritingConverter()
            ));
    }
}
```

And do the conversion there

```
public class BigDecimalToDocumentWritingConverter implements Converter<BigDecimal, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(@Nullable BigDecimal amount) {
        if (amount == null) return null;
        return String.valueOf(amount.doubleValue());
    }
}
```