# mongodb multiply aggregation operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have the following aggregation :

```
 db.a.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: {  total: { $multiply: [ 4533, 0.0001 ] } } }
   ]
)
```

The output of this aggregation is **0.45330000000000004** when it clearly should be **0.4533**. Is this a bug in the aggregation framework?

Comment: No this is not a bug. this is how mongodb gives you. you can use toFixed after getting value in nodejs. or you can use this https://github.com/debitoor/mongo-round

Comment: [Welcome to computer science](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Use [`$trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/) if you want something different.

Comment: See also: [MongoDB - What about Decimal type of value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value/11542549#11542549)

Comment: What I want to do is to round a number say 0.453334 to 4 decimals after the dot using only the aggregation framework. $trunc will truncate the number to its integer so it won't work for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay then I was going to suggest multiplying and using [`$trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/), but you can basically get away with just chaining [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) and [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) here:

```
db.a.aggregate(
   [
     { "$project": {  
       "total": {
         "$divide": [ 
           { "$multiply": [
             { "$multiply": [ 4533, 0.0001 ] },
              10000
           ]},
           10000
         ]
       } 
     }}
   ]
)
```

or just [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/)  when that is what you mean:

```
db.a.aggregate([
  { "$project": { "total": { "$divide": [ 4533, 10000 ] } } }
])
```

Which both will give you:

```
{  "total" : 0.4533 }
```

As noted, There is nothing new about floating point math and rounding, and as a general course you should avoid usage and simply apply the "non-floating point" version of what you actually mean.

The long read if you have a while is at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).